# Python package listing for images

Tags: google-dl-platform

Would it be possible to have available the different python packages installed in each deeplearning-platform image? Since there are a variety of image familys, it would be useful to know what libraries are included in each family, when selecting one. I tried to look for this information in GCR, but came up short.